# How to Compare an Image Clicked by the camera of an android phone and an image stored in firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I want to create an android Application which compares two images or more specifically two faces. The idea of the app is:
**It uses ML Kit to recognize face and then stores that image in firebase database and afterwards when the app encounters the same face it shows a match.** 
I have accomplished the detecting part just need help in the later part which is matching the images. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase ML Kit's built-in models only performs [face **detection**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces). It does not **recognize** faces. So you won't be able to use a built-in model for this.

If you want to recognize the face, and be able to compare it to the previously found face, you'll have to train and use your own [custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! Actually I am new to this and really want to learn this. Can you please guide me as to how  and from where to start or any course which would help me. A little help will be great sir!

Comment: Recommending anything specific would be off-topic here on Stack Overflow, but this seems like a good place to get started: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+train+a+machine+to+recognize+faces